# How to put route url in the echo in laravel form inside a controller?

Tags: laravel

This is the code inside the controller of my laravel:

```
        echo '
            <form action="'.$link.'" method="POST">
        '; 
        csrf_token();
        echo  '
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="reason">Total Worked Hours::</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="hours" value="'.$totalhours.'"style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="reason">Enter Your Reason:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text">
              </div>
              
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Reason</button>
            </form>

        ';
```

and the error is 419 page expired what is the proper code for this.

Comment: the proper code is using a view for your html, not putting it inside controllers. that way you can use the blade directive `@csrf` to avoid this kind of....thing

Comment: this is actually the result from the ajax so i put in the controller to echo it.  Is it not possible to create it here ?

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
csrf_token();
```

by

```
echo csrf_field();
```

Or, depending on your ajax, remove it completly.

Comment: @ZeroValue since it  fixed your issue, set it as the correct answer (btw no upvote is on the answer)